# Ensure between 7 and 10 digits at input field

Tags: html

How to ensure between 7 and 10 digits are entered using pattern attribute in HTML? I have following code:

```html
<input type="number" name="Student" id="studID" required pattern="\d{7,10}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `number` type of input elements does not support a `pattern` attribute:
See the MDN documentation in [`<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)

> In addition to the attributes commonly supported by all  types, inputs of type number support these attributes:
>
> ```
> Attribute   Description
> max         The maximum value to accept for this input
> min         The minimum value to accept for this input
> placeholder An example value to display inside the field when it's empty
> readonly    A Boolean attribute controlling whether or not the value is read-only
> step        A stepping interval to use when using up and down arrows to adjust the value, as well as for validation
> ```

[`<input type="text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) has the pattern attribute.

You could use the `min` and `max` attributes like so.

```html
<input type="number" name="Student" id="studID" min="1000000" max="9999999999">
```

Comment: I know this will work but I am required to use the pattern attribute

Comment: @IlhamRezaie Why?

Comment: In my lab, I am required to use the pattern attribute only.

Comment: But you can't use the pattern attribute on number inputs. Are you sure, you must use the number type?

Comment: For the Student ID input, I am required to use digits between 7 and 10 that are entered.

Comment: Who forces you into this technique you want to use?. You can use the `type="text"`input with your pattern

Comment: You could use some sort of JavaScript validation like this: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/KEeXep

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" name="Student" id="studID" minlength="7" maxlength="10">
```

should solve the problem you're having

Comment: But i am required to use pattern attribute

Answer (score -1):

You can add pattern attribute like this:

```
<input type="number" name="Student" id="studID" required pattern="7-10" />
```

Comment: it does not enter between 7 and 10 digits

Comment: This is because you cannot take 10 in pattern attribute,You have to choose between 0-9.